# Using __iadd__ in a lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I was trying to solve this little challenge:

> You want a defaultdict that uses a different value every time a
>   non-existent key is looked up, i.e. a counter; 1 for the first
>   non-existent key, 2 for the second, etc.

I was able to solve it like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(a=[0]):
    a[0]+=1
    return a[0]

s=defaultdict(f)
```

The bonus was to try to do this in one line.

```
s=defaultdict(lambda a=[0]: (a[0]+=1))
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax  _________^

Is there a way to do this in a lambda? Update the mutable default arg and return?

Comment: You could call `__iadd__` explicitly, except `int` objects don't define `__iadd__`; `a[0] += 1` is treated the same as `a[0] = a[0] + 1`.

Comment: Well, generally there is no way to use += in a lambda because that makes it a statement instead of an expression. The only thing that comes to my mind is using the `__iadd__` method directly, but as @chepner pointed out, that is probably not possible.

Comment: Like chepner said, `int` doesn't have an `__iadd__` method that you can call explicitly, but you can *emulate* it: `s=defaultdict(lambda a=[0]: a.__setitem__(0, a[0]+1) or a[0])`

Comment: @chepner I attempted to import operators and use `d=defaultdict(lambda _=[0]: operator.iadd(_[0],1)[0])`, but get `'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: I feel like python has enough black magic that somehow you can mimic the behavior of `a[0]+=1` by direct call. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `... += ...` is a statement, not an expression. You could call `__iadd__` explicitly, *except* ...
2. `int` doesn't define `__iadd__`; `a[0] += 1` is just implemented as `a[0] = a[0] + 1`.

What you need to do is call `__setitem__` explicitly to update the 0th element of the default list value. That returns `None`, not `a[0]`, so you'll also need an `or` expression to return the value of `a[0]` (since `None or x == x`):

```
>>> s = defaultdict(lambda a=[0]: a.__setitem__(0, a[0] + 1) or a[0])
>>> s[6]
1
>>> s[9]
2
>>> s[6]
1
>>> s[8]
3
```

(I'd write `defaultdict(itertools.count(0).__next__)` myself.)

Comment: Where can I learn more about this line:`a[0] += 1 is just implemented as a[0] = a[0] + 1`? Where does that transform happen?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__. In short, `x += y` becomes (more or less) `x = x + y` if `x.__iadd__` is not defined.

Comment: (Note, though, that `x += y` generates the `INPLACE_ADD` byte code regardless; the "replacement" occurs in the implementation of the byte code in the interpreter.)

Answer (score 3):

[`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to the rescue:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda a = [0]: operator.setitem(a, 0, a[0] + 1) or a[0])
```

Comment: Any idea how to use `operator.iadd` in place? Or does the fact `a[0]` being an int block this?

Comment: `iadd` on an `int` doesn't do what you'd like - `operator.iadd(a[0], 1) # 1` but then `a` is still `[0]`.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a `getter` argument to `iadd` that let you say `operator.iadd(a, 1, getter = operator.itemgetter(0))`, but there isn't at the current moment.

Answer (score 2):

Do imports count as part of your one line?

If not you could use itertools.count

```
from itertools import count
d = defaultdict(count().__next__)
```

If they do you could use the slightly ugly hack

```
d = defaultdict(__import__('itertools').count().__next__)
```

Comment: There are a number of other ways to solve this problem. `d = __import__("collections").defaultdict(lambda c=[0]: c.append(c.pop() + 1) or c[0])`
I am more interested about the __iadd__ issue

Answer (score 2):

While there are many ways to solve this problem on one line, I see a lot of questions regarding whether `operator.iadd` can be used here.

It cannot.

Sure, it would *appear* that

```
s = defaultdict(lambda a=[0]: operator.iadd(a[0], 1))
```

would work, but it does not.

The reason comes from the [offical docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

> Many operations have an “in-place” version. Listed below are functions providing a more primitive access to in-place operators than the usual syntax does; for example, the statement x += y is equivalent to x = operator.iadd(x, y). Another way to put it is to say that z = operator.iadd(x, y) is equivalent to the compound statement z = x; z += y.
>
> In those examples, note that when an in-place method is called, the computation and assignment are performed in two separate steps. The in-place functions listed below only do the first step, calling the in-place method. The second step, assignment, is not handled.
>
> For immutable targets such as strings, numbers, and tuples, the updated value is computed, but not assigned back to the input variable:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> iadd(a, ' world')
'hello world'
>>> a
'hello'
```

> For mutable targets such as lists and dictionaries, the in-place method will perform the update, so no subsequent assignment is necessary.

Because `int` objects are immutable, you cannot update `a[0]` with `iadd`.

(I know this was said in other answers; I just thought a definite answer with a link to the Python docs might be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a mutable type like list to keep track of the count?

```
s = defaultdict(lambda a=[] : len(a.__iadd__([1])))
```

To reduce memory usage:

```
s = defaultdict(lambda a=[0] : a.__iadd__([a.pop() + 1])[0])
```

Comment: Haha, That is a cool solution. Maybe a bit more memory intensive but cool

Comment: That's a lot of extra memory.